# Why does Thread.start() take so long?

Tags: python, multithreading

I made this simple script,

```html
from threading import Thread


def load():
    print(list(range(1000000000)))


def create_single_thread_func(numThread):
    def _create_single_thread():
        print('Starting thread', numThread)
        Thread(target=load).start()
        print('Started load', numThread)
    return _create_single_thread


def init_threads(numThreads):
    print('Starting thread init function')
    for i in range(numThreads):
        singleThreadFunc = create_single_thread_func(i)
        Thread(target=singleThreadFunc).start()


Thread(target=init_threads, args=(1000000, )).start()
```

And wanted to see how long it would take. I thought that all the threads would start one after the other, but here is the result:

```
Starting thread init function
Starting thread 0
Starting thread 1
```

The code doesn't terminate here, but pauses. Why do the rest not start?

Comment: Looks like that call to `list(range(1000000000))` is eating up gigabytes of RAM to store a giant list of numbers in each thread.  I suspect the performance problem you are seeing is a side effect of that -- replace it with `print(range(1000000000))` and the slowdown goes away.

Comment: you thought 1 million threads would all start right away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is memory. A list of `1e9` elements done 1e6 times?

Or even just do the line `a = list(range(1000000000))` itself and see how it takes a lot of time. If one int always took 4-byte and there was no overhead of the list itself, that would still be ~4GB for one list!

But if you change your list size to e.g. just 1000, your threads will work normally. Also added counter of active threads out of curiosity:

```
from threading import Thread, active_count


def load():
    print(list(range(1000)))


def create_single_thread_func(numThread):
    def _create_single_thread():
        print('Starting thread', numThread, 'Active threads:', active_count())
        Thread(target=load).start()
        print('Started load', numThread)
    return _create_single_thread


def init_threads(numThreads):
    print('Starting thread init function')
    for i in range(numThreads):
        singleThreadFunc = create_single_thread_func(i)
        Thread(target=singleThreadFunc).start()

Thread(target=init_threads, args=(1000000, )).start()
```

It's bad idea to run it, still, because 1e6 is huge and it will take time to even go to 100k, but it *works*

Comment: How high does active_count go?

Comment: @KellyBundy Let me test it again because I killed it while writing the answer...  If I remove the print from load and just run it, looking at how it goes: most was <100 active, around 200k it jumped to 3-digits (it's scrolling fast but I noticed some 1xx and 2xx), in 270k it started jumping into thousands (up and down - you can notice cleanups), near 300k it went into 20+k, now it's in 370k and it's back to <100 with occasional jump into hundreds... and now back into growing past 10k. So quite a mix. I'm too lazy to do a real analysis, this is just for fun

Comment: Thanks. Interesting how much it jumped around, especially that it got back down to <100 after having exploded to 20+k.